# ReferenceError: g is not defined loopback extended models

Tags: loopbackjs

I am having a nearly identical problem to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716166/error-using-extended-loopback-model).  When a `user` model is created, the following error is returned:

```js
ReferenceError: g is not defined
    at new ModelConstructor (eval at createModelClassCtor (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js:671:21), <anonymous>:10:27)
    at user.ModelBaseClass._initProperties (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model.js:349:28)
    at user.ModelBaseClass (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model.js:60:8)
    at user.Model (eval at createModelClassCtor (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js:671:21), <anonymous>:12:24)
    at user.PersistedModel (eval at createModelClassCtor (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js:671:21), <anonymous>:12:24)
    at user.User (eval at createModelClassCtor (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js:671:21), <anonymous>:12:24)
    at new user (eval at createModelClassCtor (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js:671:21), <anonymous>:12:24)
    at Function.DataAccessObject.create (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:359:13)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:1262:13
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:2175:62
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:2111:9
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1012:9
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:359:16
    at eachOfArrayLike (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:928:9)
    at eachOf (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:990:5)
    at _asyncMap (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1005:5)
    at Object.map (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:995:16)
    at allCb (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:2025:13)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:1155:9
    at result (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:414:17)
    at executeCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:406:9)
    at handleCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)
```

Here are my models:

**user.json**:

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "plural": "users",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type" : "string",
      "id" : true,
      "required" : true,
      "defaultFn" : "guid"
    },
    "type": {
      "type" : "[string]",
      "required" : true,
      "default" : ["student"]
    },
    "full_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "office" : {
      "type": "string",
      "required" : false
    },
    "profile_img": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "departmentId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "department": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "department"
    },
    "syncedcalendar" : {
      "type" : "hasMany",
      "model" : "syncedcalendar"
    },
    "accessTokens": {
       "type": "hasMany",
       "model": "accessToken",
       "foreignKey": "userId",
        "options": {
          "disableInclude": true
        }
     }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**accessToken.json**

```
{
  "name": "accessToken",
  "plural": "accessTokens",
  "base": "AccessToken",
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "idInjection": false,
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/lib/model-builder.js#L671

g is `require('strong-globalize')()`,   

Have you tried reinstalling all your packages?  And you're using the latest version of loopback, correct?

Answer (score 1):

The error above (in both this case and my previous issue) resulted because loopback could not parse the model's json file.  In this case, it was the `type` property of `user`:

```
"type": {
  "type" : "[string]",
  "required" : true,
  "default" : ["student"]
},
```

It seems the `default` cannot be an array.  Removing this default and enforcing this default in a hook resolved the issue.

Comment: how do we enforce this default in a hook resolved the issue?

Comment: @sifavahora inside `Model.observe("before save"...)` you can check if `type` is set. If it's undefined, then set it as `["student"]`

Answer (score 1):

I went through an issue that resembled yours. And yes, the error stack gives too little useful info. It should instead say: "please stick to Loopback types" because that's the problem. You're stuck with [Loopback types](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/LoopBack-types.html).

In your case, the parser couldn not handle an array. Well, it turns out it won't parse an un recognized type string either. For example, if you try to declare a property as `integer`:

```
 "id":
    {
      "type": "Integer", <-----  not a loopback type
      "id": 1,
      "mysql":
      {
        "columnName": "id",
        "dataType": "int",
     }
  },
```

It will throw, because the native type is `Number`. You can `format` it as integer, but don't mess with its `type`.

```
 "id":
    {
      "type": "Number",  <----  one of loopback types. Integer is not one of them
      "id": 1,
      "mysql":
      {
        "columnName": "id",
        "dataType": "int",
      }
      "format":"integer" <---- here's where you can format or cast as desired
  },
```

If your database values are json-like (so they should rehidrate as arrays and objects) just declare them as Objects.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22481531)

Comment: @DebanjanB my answer was poorly writen and I apologize. However I wanted to show that it's not a problem of array properties vs text properties. The error will be thrown for text values too if they aren't in Loopback's white list. I rewrote most of my answer, but I'm open to delete it if more people see fit.